# Getting "Sorry, we were unable to load that OpenAPI definition. Please either supply a URL or a path on your filesystem." GAMESHIFT

Tags: solana-program

Getting the above error when trying to use any GAMESHIFT features.

Was working fine yesterday.

```
Error registering user: Error: Sorry, we were unable to load that OpenAPI definition. Please either supply a URL or a path on your filesystem.
    at SdkCache.load (/root/tappyfish/v2/node_modules/api/src/cache.js:95:15)
    at loadFromCache (/root/tappyfish/v2/node_modules/api/src/index.js:88:34)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (/root/tappyfish/v2/node_modules/api/src/index.js:121:19)
    at /root/tappyfish/v2/server.js:277:54
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/tappyfish/v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/root/tappyfish/v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/root/tappyfish/v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/tappyfish/v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /root/tappyfish/v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/root/tappyfish/v2/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
```

did I break something or is api down?

Cheers.

Tom

Comment: Solved by clearing server cache,
```npm uninstall api --save

then npm install api --save```

godspeed brothers & sisters